# Consider something separate from each other Vs Consider something separately from each other

Tags: difference

1: Do not consider the sentences **separate** from each other.

2: Do not consider the sentences **separately** from each other.

Comment: Please spell out words. This is an English website, not twitter.

Comment: "separately from each other" is redundant. The "from each other" is unnecessary. Beyond that, what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

The word "separate" is an adjective, and can modify the noun "sentences".  The word "separately" is an adverb and can modify the verb "consider".

1: The sentences are joined.

2: Consider them at the same time.